# Create iPhone Application Bundle for Release in Xcode 4.0.1

Tags: iphone, release, bundle

I am having trouble figuring out how to create an application bundle for release, it does not seem to be done the way it was in older versions of Xcode.

I tried looking for documentation, but I can not find anything that looks like it contains the answer.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442